# Symfony 2.8 - It is correct that the authentication token is recreated on each request?

Tags: symfony, authentication

I am identifying access to certain routes through x509 digital certificate (pre-authentication).
For this I defined the security.yml as follows:

```
- security:
   providers:
       x509Provider_Provider:
           id: x509Provider_Service
   firewalls:
       dev:
           pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
           security: false
       xes:
           pattern: ^/xes
           x509: 
               provider: x509Provider_Provider
               user: "SSL_CLIENT_S_DN"
   access_control:
       - { path: ^/xes, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
```

Where I get the SSL_CLIENT_S_DN and I use as username.

In the Provider

```
 x509Provider class implements UserProviderInterface
```

consult the database if the user exists and has access permissions and based on this
I create an object

```
**x509User class implements UserInterface, EquatableInterface**
```

where I store information access permissions and other data.

Apparently it works correctly, in the Symfony profiler I have a user with their roles and marked as authenticated.

The problem is: whenever I access a route (pattern: ^ / XES) the authentication process and access to the database is launched to obtain roles and user permissions.

It should not authenticate only the first time and once created the session use in subsequent requests ?.

I hope I have explained my question correctly.

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

> Nowadays, it's quite usual to authenticate the user via an API key
>   (when developing a web service for instance). The API key is provided
>   for every request and is passed as a query string parameter or via an
>   HTTP header.

I think that it's the same for the token.